# Using PrefixList in EC2 Routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have the following prefix list in CloudFormation but I do not find anyway to use it in the EC2 Route tables.

```
MyPrefixList: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::PrefixList
    Properties: 
      AddressFamily: IPv4
      Entries: 
      - Cidr: 192.168.0.0/16
        Description: Private Space Class B
```

The `DestinationCidrBlock` only accepts a string it seems.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-route.html#cfn-ec2-route-routetableid

```
Type: AWS::EC2::Route
Properties: 
  CarrierGatewayId: String
  DestinationCidrBlock: String
  DestinationIpv6CidrBlock: String
  EgressOnlyInternetGatewayId: String
  GatewayId: String
  InstanceId: String
  LocalGatewayId: String
  NatGatewayId: String
  NetworkInterfaceId: String
  RouteTableId: String
  TransitGatewayId: String
  VpcEndpointId: String
  VpcPeeringConnectionId: String
```

Is this feature still missing?

Answer (score 0):

Its **not supported** yet. But there is already a github issue for that:

- [AWS::EC2::Route support for DestinationPrefixListId](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/572)